# Iterate through a DataTable to find elements in a List object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datarow, generic-list

As I iterate through a **DataTable** object, I need to check each of its **DataRow** objects against the items in a generic string **List**.

I found a [blog post](http://www.csharpcourses.com/2008/05/how-to-find-object-in-generic-list.html) using the List's Find method along with a delegate, but whereas that example has a separate class (Person), I'm attempting something like the following using an instance of the **string** object:

```
// My definition of the List object.
List<string> lstAccountNumbers = new List<string>();
...

// I populate the List via its Add method.
...

foreach (DataRow drCurrentRow in dtMyDataTable.Rows) 
{
    if (lstAccounts.Find(delegate(string sAccountNumber) { return sAccountNumber == drCurrentRow["AccountNumber"]; })
    {
        Found_DoSomething();
    }
    else
    {
        NotFound_DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

However, with this syntax I'm receiving "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'" for the **if** block.

Could someone please clarify what I'm doing wrong and how best to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same Delegate Different method.
You want to use Exists Not Find. 
Find Returns a value while exists returns a bool.

```
if (lstAccounts.Exists(delegate(string sAccountNumber) { return sAccountNumber == drCurrentRow["AccountNumber"]; })
```

Comment: Could you mark this as the correct answer, that would be awsome

Comment: @Darth Continent: do not listen to him he is the devil in flesh

Comment: According to your profile @"SO give me back my rep" you are evil, not I.

Answer (score 1):

why would not this work for you?

```
foreach (DataRow drCurrentRow in dtMyDataTable.Rows) 
{
    if (lstAccounts.Contains(drCurrentRow["AccountNumber"].ToString()))
    {
        Found_DoSomething();
    }
    else
    {
        NotFound_DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `if (lstAccounts.Find` part.

This `Find` will return a string if found and the `if` is expecting a bool output.

Change your statement to use `Exists` or compare your original value to the `Find` result.

Answer (score 1):

The list **Find** method returns a **string** so you should compare it using **Equals** method or **==**.In that case the if condition will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

try using linq, you can create a helper that takes in col name etc...

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));

```
        DataRow row;
        row = table.NewRow();
        row["col1"] = "123";
        table.Rows.Add(row);
        row = table.NewRow();
        row["col1"] = "456";
        table.Rows.Add(row);

        LinqList<DataRow> rows = new LinqList<DataRow>(table.Rows);
        // do a simple select
       DataRow [] selectedRows = (from r in rows where (string)r["col1"] == "123" select r).ToArray();

        if(selectedRows.Length > 0)
        {
            lable1.Text = "success";
        }
        else
        {
            lable1.Text = "failed";
        }
    }
}


// simple wrapper that implements IEnumerable<T>
internal class LinqList<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerable items;

    internal LinqList(IEnumerable items)
    {
        this.items = items;
    }

    #region IEnumerable<DataRow> Members
    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (T item in items)
            yield return item;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        IEnumerable<T> ie = this;
        return ie.GetEnumerator();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

taken code from this url
[Iterate through a DataTable to find elements in a List object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509109/iterate-through-a-datatable-to-find-elements-in-a-list-object)